# Getting Started With Django video series - issue with Postgres database creation

Tags: django, postgresql

I am on a virtualenv running on vagrant following http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/en/lessons/introduction-and-launch/, and when I type:

```
$ sudo su postgres
```

I get asked to enter a password:

```
$ [sudo] password for postgres:
```

Does anyone have any tips for how to find the password? I'm confused that I'm even getting this password request, since previously, this is what happened:

```
createuser: creation of new role failed: ERROR: role "vagrant" already exists
postgres@precise64:/vagrant/projects/microblog$ createuser -P
could not change directory to "/vagrant/projects/microblog"

(blog-venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/projects/microblog$ createdb microblog
createdb:     database creation failed: ERROR: permission denied to create database

(blog-venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/projects/microblog$ sudo su postgres     

postgres@precise64:/vagrant/projects/microblog$ dropuser vagrant
could not change directory to "/vagrant/projects/microblog"
postgres@precise64:/vagrant/projects/microblog$sudo -u postgres psql postgres is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.

postgres@precise64:/vagrant/projects/microblog/microblog$ sudo su postgres
[sudo] password for postgres:
```

Ultimately I'm trying to make the `createdb microblog` create a database for me in Postgres, but I'm running into these strange password request issues.

Comment: What about "sudo su postgres psql"? But use your account to do this. Linux is asking you for a password because you became postgres and want to gain root access

Comment: Ah, I just realized that I was in postgres@precise64 and not vagrant@precise64. How do I get back to root?

Comment: Logout, then login again? Please note you never are root: you use a user account that can become root

Comment: Ahhh, I finally figured out how to exit from postgres@ to vagrant@: I just need to type "exit"!

Comment: @Alvaro Huh? `sudo -u postgres` is all you need. It's beyond me why people keep on (ab)using `su` for this.